# AWS Glue Spark job does not scale when partitioning DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I am developing a Glue Spark job script using Glue development endpoint which has 4 DPUs allocated. According to Glue [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-debug-capacity.html) 1 DPU equals to 2 executors and each executor can run 4 tasks. 1 DPU is reserved for master and 1 executor is for the driver. Now when my development endpoint has 4 DPUs I expect to have 5 executors and 20 tasks.

The script I am developing loads 1 million rows using JDBC connection. Then I coalesce the one million row partition into 5 partitions and write it to S3 bucket using the option `maxRecordsPerFile = 100000`. The whole process takes 34 seconds. Then I change the number of partitions to 10 and the job runs for 34 seconds again. So if I have 20 tasks available why is the script taking the same amount of time to complete with more partitions?

Edit: I started executing the script with an actual job, not development endpoint. I set the amount of workers to 10 and worker type to standard. Looking at metrics I can see that I have only 9 executors instead of 17 and only 1 executor is doing something and the rest are idle.

Code:

```
...

df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", job_config["jdbcDriver"]).option("url", jdbc_config["url"]).option(
    "user", jdbc_config["user"]).option("password", jdbc_config["password"]).option("dbtable", query).option("fetchSize", 50000).load()

df.coalesce(17)

df.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option(
    "compression", "gzip").option("maxRecordsPerFile", 1000000).save(job_config["s3Path"])

...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is highly likely a limitation of the connections being opened to your jdbc data source, too few connections reduce parallelism too much may burden your database. Increase the degree of parallelism by tuning the options [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/run-jdbc-parallel-read-job.html).

Since you are reading as a data frame, you can set the upper lower bound and the partition columns. More can be found [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/08/17/apache-spark-makes-slow-mysql-queries-10x-faster/).

To [size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-debug-capacity.html) your DPUs correctly, I would suggest linking the [spark-ui](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-spark-ui-jobs.html), it could help narrow down where all the time is spend and the actual distribution of your tasks when you look at the DAG.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The first link you provided is about DynamicFrames and because I have to read data between two dates (the latest data since last run) I don't think it's possible to use DynamicFrames. I also thought that when you partition a DataFrame the partitions are distributed evenly among the executors and tasks within them and therefore multiple executors should be used. By the way if I use a WHERE clause in my query does the upper and lower boundaries partition and read just the data I've filtered or does it still read the whole table?